# Is it possible to test layouts in Calabash?

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, calabash

Does calabash have some predefined functions to test UI elements placement? For example:

```
Given I am on some screen
Then I see element1 LEFT OF element2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that comes to my mind is function `find_coordinate(uiquery)` (it is included in Calabash). This function returns an array of coordinates of elements (first is position on `x` axis and the second on `y`).

Usage example:

```
And /^I see '(.*?)' on the left of '(.*?)'$/ do |name1, name2|
  element1_x = find_coordinate("* marked:'#{name1}'")[0]
  element2_x = find_coordinate("* marked:'#{name2}'")[0]

  unless element1_x < element2_x
    raise "Element '#{name1}' is not on the left of element '#{name2}'!"
  end
end
```